# Javascript popup not working

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Whats wrong with the below page?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin(url, w, h)
{
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
w=window.open(url, '_blank', 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, location=no, toolbar=no, top='+top+', left='+left+', 'false');
w.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin(about:blank, 200, 200)" />

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I click the button nothing happens.

Using chrome

Comment: What errors do you see in your JS console? The quotes in the `w=window.open()` line appear to be off a bit near the end, particularly near the `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin(url, w, h)
{
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
w=window.open(url, '_blank', width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars='no', menubar='no', resizable='no', location='no', toolbar='no', top='+top+', left='+left+', 'false');
w.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin('about:blank', 200, 200); return false;" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i was getting there, just put quotes around the 'no's myself. ninjad :D

Answer (score 3):

you Have 2 syntax errors, one in your onClick attribute, your `about:blank` isn't quoted
Two, in window.open you have `+'` at the end of you second argument also you have the third argument as a string, it should be boolean.

Answer (score 2):

A unique bit of relevant trivia:
at least in recent releases of IE, 9.0.8112.16241 (vista/win7) and 8.0.6001.18072 (xp), programmatically do a `window.open(‘about:blank’)` and the programmable `focus()` will be stuck in the address bar showing “**about:blank**”.
**Note:** `window.open(”)` with an empty string URL is the same as `window.open(‘about:blank’)`.

Adding the option `location=no` works around this based on IE security setting
 `Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars`

However they default badly (force address bar). Simplest I’ve found is to have users set our site in their security settings as “trusted” where the default “medium” settings do not force the address bar to show.

Using a dummy URI `javascript:popup=1` in IE 8 did work around this, but that may open in a new tab based on settings which may not work for you.

Relevant custom security setting:

- Where: Tool->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level->Miscellaneous
- Value: Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars:
  enable

***Note:** mine is a legacy web based “application” that employs the legitimately useful design of popups which are beneficial (no one has ripped them out of “Word” yet). It is enough challenge for those of us damaged as this useful UI mechanism has been marred by scammers and hackers that I implore you to resist further beating us up with the non-productive “don’t use popups” tangential interjection.*

Test code (`onloadJSServerSidePage` works, `onloadJSClientSidePage` has issues):

http://forus.com/csm/code/iepopup/testPopupFocus.html

Optional “testPopupFocusContent.html” for `onloadJSServerSidePag`:

http://forus.com/csm/code/iepopup/testPopupFocusContent.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<input type="button" 
       value="Open window" 
       onclick="openWin('about:blank', 200, 200);" />
```

I think the colon in the URL param in your function call is causing the problem - if it's a string it should be in quotes.

EDIT: added a semi colon - this seems to work for me.

Comment: Sorry, still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your `false` at the end of the `w=window.open()` line isn't properly quoted/concatenated.

Comment: Have you looked in your console for errors?  Just telling me that it's not working isn't helping me help you.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: openWin is not defined test.html:15
onclick

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) test.html:8

Comment: Okay. openWin is not defined because you're calling it without quoting the URL string (about:blank).  And your unexpected token on line 8 is because you're not concatenating properly.  `false` should not be a string either.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin(url, w, h)
{
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
w=window.open(url, '_blank', 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, location=no, toolbar=no, top='+top+', left='+left+);
w.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin('about:blank', 200, 200)" />

</body>
</html

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWin(url, w, h)
{
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
w=window.open(url, '_blank', 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, location=no, toolbar=no, 

top='+top+', left='+left+', false);
w.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin('about:blank', 200, 200)" />

</body>
</html>

Comment: I can't make sense of the HTML you're posting in the comments, so no need to continue.

Answer (score 1):

here the last argument was malformed and corrected removing a '

```
   w=window.open(url, '_blank', 'width='+w+', height='+h+', scrollbars=no, menubar=no, 
    resizable=no, location=no, toolbar=no, top='+top+', left='+left+', false');
```

in html calling code,

```
  <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin('http://www.google.com', 200, 200)" />
```

in the url part you can have an either absolute url or relative one..

hope this helps..